# How to transform multiple rows of json objects into sql table structured data?

Tags: sql, json, database, api, ssis

I have created Web API using a Script Task in SSIS that retrieves weather data in JSON format into a SQL database table using this tutorial: [Weather API SSIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6t2mB1kH6ZI). In the tutorial example there is only one set of coordinates that are being used which gives us one row in the database table with the JSON object.

```html
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
#endregion

namespace ST_6f60bececd8f4f94afaf758869590918
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            string Longitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Longitude"].Value.ToString();
            string Latitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Latitude"].Value.ToString();
            string municipality = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Municipality"].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Longitude:" + Longitude + ", Latitude:" + Latitude);
            var url = @"https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact.json?lat="+Latitude+"&lon="+Longitude+"";
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            req.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            var syncClient = new WebClient();
            syncClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "acmeweathersite.com support@acmeweathersite.com");
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

            string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Weather;Integrated Security=True;";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand Storproc =
                  new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Weather] (JSONData)
                                    select @JSONData", conn);
                Storproc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JSONData", content.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                Storproc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
            // TODO: Add your code here

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

[image]

After that I take the JSON object that is retrieved from the Script task code posted above and insert it into a new table in sql data table format:

```html
declare @JSON nvarchar(max)
select @JSON = [JSONData]
FROM [Weather].[dbo].[Weather]
;with cteTemp as
(SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.properties.timeseries')
WITH (   
   time datetime '$.time',   
   air_temperature nvarchar(50) '$.data.instant.details.air_temperature',
   wind_speed nvarchar(50) '$.data.instant.details.wind_speed',
   precipitation_amount_next_1_hour nvarchar(50) '$.data.next_1_hours.details.precipitation_amount',
   symbol_code_next_1_hour nvarchar(50) '$.data.next_1_hours.summary.symbol_code',
   precipitation_amount_next_6_hour nvarchar(50) '$.data.next_6_hours.details.precipitation_amount',
   symbol_code_next_6_hour nvarchar(50) '$.data.next_6_hours.summary.symbol_code'
)
)

insert into [dbo].[WeatherByHour]([time],[air_temperature],wind_speed,precipitation_amount_next_1_hour,symbol_code_next_1_hour,precipitation_amount_next_6_hour,symbol_code_next_6_hour)
select [time],
       [air_temperature],
       wind_speed,
       precipitation_amount_next_1_hour,
       symbol_code_next_1_hour,
       precipitation_amount_next_6_hour,
       symbol_code_next_6_hour
from cteTemp;
```

[image]

The next step now is that I have created table with multiple coordinates that I will use as a parameter variable in my Script task and adding a foreach loop:

[image]

This will now give me 3 rows of JSON objects one for each set of coordinates that exists in my Coordinates table being used as variable parameter in the URL API:

[image]
[image]

The issue I am having now is that when I insert the JSON objects into my WeatherByHour table it only uses the first row of JSON object with the first set of coordinates which in my example gives me 83 rows but ideally I would like it to result in 83 + 83 + 83 = 249 rows. What would be the best solution here, to create one big JSON array object inside the script task or somehow loop through all the JSON object rows in the Weather table and inserting them in the WeatherByHour table ?

These are all the tables being used in my example:

```html
USE [Weather]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Weather]    Script Date: 2021-03-14 13:55:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Weather](
    [JSONData] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [Weather]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[WeatherByHour]    Script Date: 2021-03-14 13:56:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherByHour](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [time] [datetime] NULL,
    [air_temperature] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [wind_speed] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [precipitation_amount_next_1_hour] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [symbol_code_next_1_hour] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [precipitation_amount_next_6_hour] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [symbol_code_next_6_hour] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WeatherByHour] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


create table Coordinates(
             Municipality nvarchar(50),
             Latitide nvarchar(50),
             Longitude nvarchar(50)
             )
INSERT INTO Coordinates (Municipality, Latitide, Longitude)
VALUES (114, 59.5166667, 17.9),
        (115, 59.5833333, 18.2),
        (117, 59.5, 18.45)
```

Comment: @Zhorov Do you know m8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross apply to turn the timeseries into rows of json.

For your example [Weather].[dbo].[Weather] table above, you will end up with 3 (no coordinates) x N (timeseries per coordinate).

```sql
SELECT s.value, 
    --JSON_VALUE(w.JSONData,'$.geometry.coordinates[1]') AS [latitude],
    --JSON_VALUE(w.JSONData,'$.geometry.coordinates[0]') AS [longitude],
    CAST(JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.time') AS datetime) AS [time],
    JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data.instant.details.air_temperature') as [air_temperature],
    JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.data.next_1_hours.details.precipitation_amount') as [precipitation_amount_next_1_hour] 
FROM [Weather].[dbo].[Weather] w
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(w.JSONData,'$.properties.timeseries') s
```